# JQGrid API documentation

Tags: jqgrid

I am having a bear of a time finding any updated JQGrid documentation.

the best one I could find is over a year old: http://www.secondpersonplural.ca/jqgriddocs/index.htm

Is there a new one somewhere?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look at [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:jqgriddocs). You can find the reference on the documentation from [here](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=15).

**UPDATED:** The new features implemented in the [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) fork of jqGrid are described [here](https://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html), in [the wiki articles](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki) and in READMEs to every version of free jqGrid.

Comment: Thanks Oleg - i have been to both of those sites.....took me a while to find what I was looking for. which was http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options

Comment: A table of options is here http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options and list of methods are here http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods

Answer (score 0):

http://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/user-guide/basic-grid/
contains the most up to date information on the official paid version Guriddo JQGrid.

https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki for documentation on the free fork of JQGrid created by Oleg.